# docker-compose build with url context and local Dockerfile

Tags: docker, docker-compose

The docker build context is defined as [either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a git repository](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#context).

With the `docker` command, it's possible to build an image using

- a local context and a local Dockerfile:

  `docker build -t foobar [-f Dockerfile.local] .`
- a remote context and a remote Dockerfile:

  `docker build -t foobar https://github.com/foobar/foobar [-f Dockerfile.remote]`
- a remote context and a local Dockerfile

  `docker build -t foobar https://github.com/foobar/foobar -f- < Dockerfile.local`

The first two options easily translate to docker-compose:

```
services:
  first:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.local
  second:
    build:
      context: https://github.com/foobar/foobar
      dockerfile: Dockerfile.remote
```

The official documentation says nothing about injecting a local Dockerfile to a remote context with docker-compose. Is it possible?

Comment: I guess the easiest way to check it is to set up a public git test repo and just upload a Dockerfile with a custom name like "my-testfile" and test it with that one. Atleast the documentation doesnt say that it's not possible. So i guess it does! But never tried it before. Or what do you exactly mean by 'injecting a local Dockerfile to a remote context'? You want to explicitly set the name of the used Dockerfile on the git repository, right?

Comment: I'm asking if it's possible because I have tried and failed so far. The second example does already set the name and path of the Dockerfile on the repository, but it must exist in the repository beforehand.  What I'm trying to do is using a Dockerfile when there is none in the remote repository (as a means for separating concerns), or replacing the existing one by sending one to the context. It works with `docker` (third example). I'm looking for a way to do the same in a 'docker-compose.yml' file.

Comment: Oh so you want to Upload a Dockerfile to the repository? (If it does not exist yet)
Or do you want a local fallback if the one in the repository doesnt exist?
Or do you want to use the remote one and "overwrite" it by a local one?

Comment: That's it. Without modifying the repository.

Comment: on which of my three question do you refer? (Sorry, edited my comment twice...)

Comment: My goal is to use one I define locally regardless if there is already one. If there is one, I replace it with mine. If there is none, I use mine. So I guess you can see that as either "uploading" or "overwriting".